# Same topic name allowed in multiple topics

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-proposals

In [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) there are **three** topics named `Exceptions`. I consider this as a bug that many topics can have the exact same name.

Also, there are even more topics: `Exception handling` and `Catching and raising exceptions` and so on. We need some kind of quick merge/close as a duplicate since there is not much else to `Exception handling` as there is in `Catching and raising exceptions` really. Now I need two approves to do one merge here, and am afraid that if I stack many merges, then they'd cancel each other.

Comment: Yes, that is a bit of an issue I encountered as well.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue in C# "Lock Statement". Currently there are two topics with this name

Comment: I think it's caused by topic suggestions, at least partially. If two users start a new topic based on a suggestion, and both topics get approved, it results in duplicate topics. You also can't see other users' drafts before creating your own, and even then drafts are full of empty topics. It's a mess.